# Angular 6 zip is deprecated: resultSelector is no longer supported, pipe to map instead

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

In Angular 6 zip is deprecated:
 
tslint gives me the following message:

`zip is deprecated: resultSelector is no longer supported, pipe to map instead`

How can I upgrade this following code:

```
import {interval, from, zip} from 'rxjs';
let testArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
array$ = from(testArray);
inter$ = interval(1000);
numbersOverTime$ = zip(array$, inter$, (item, i) => item);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Simply by piping `zip` and `map`:

```
numbersOverTime$ = zip(array$, inter$)
  .pipe(
    map(([item, i]) => item)
  );
```

Comment: I still seem to be getting this linting error: zip is deprecated: resultSelector is no longer supported, pipe to map instead

Comment: What I showed here doesn't use the `resultSelector` parameter so the error must be comming from somewhere else in your code

Comment: @apollowebdesigns where you able to identify the problem?